# Compiled against different NODE_MODULE_VERSION - Tree-sitter parser, ATOM package

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, atom-editor, treesitter

I have created a tree-sitter parser that is parsing some legacy SAP language we use in order to make a package compatible for ATOM.
I will be very literate in my actions taken, as I am not very confident where I messed up.

According to the tree-sitter documentation many guides I read - I've done the following:

Added D:\path-to-project\node_modules.bin to PATH

```
npm install -g node-gyp (I have installed the dependencies - MSVC 2017 and Python 2.7)
```

Created a new directory and cd to it:

```
npm init (followed the dialog)
npm install
npm install --save-dev nan
npm install --save-dev tree-sitter-cli
```

Now we can create our tree-sitter grammar.js file and generate the tree-sitter parser so I did:

Created the grammar.js and wrote down the necessary grammar
Opened CMD, cd to project folder and:

```
tree-sitter generate
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
tree-sitter test (To check if the parser is working correctly, which it does)
```

Accordingly now I can integrate the parser inside an ATOM package.
So I published the tree-sitter parser that I created to npm via - 'npm publish' then:

I created a package from ATOMs Generate package function, created a "grammar" directory in the package and a .cson file with the following values:

```
name: 'Human readable name'
scopeName: 'A unique, stable identifier for the language.'
type: 'tree-sitter' (indicates that we are using tree-sitter grammar not TextMate one)
parser: 'Here we must the npm package name that we published to NPM' 
fileTypes: ['array of file extensions that the package will run on for example 'cpp'']
```

Here is where it gets interesting. After 'npm install my-npm-package-name' inside my ATOM package directory I get an error inside ATOM:

```
The module '\\?\D:\Users\myUser\github\my-ATOM-package-name\node_modules\my-tree-sitter-npm-package    
\build\Release\my-tree-sitter-npm-package_binding.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 73. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`). 
in D:\Users\myUser\.atom\packages\my-ATOM-package-name\grammars\the-cson-file-mentioned.cson
```

From the web investigation I did, this is due that ATOM uses different NodeJs version from what I am using (NodeJs v 12.4.0).
This is where I am stuck at, after many tries to recompile with 'electron-rebuild' I have given up with no success and decided that I need more experienced helper.

I am developing and installing on Windows. NodeJS is installed with nvm and I am developing with v12.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue.
Apparently or not so apparently you should:

```
npm install --save-dev electron@9.3.5 (the current electron version atom was at the time of the last edit of the answer)
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild 

electron-rebuild --version 9.3.5 (the current electron version atom was using at the time of the last edit of the answer)
```

If it still complains that you are running different version you should:

```
node-gyp rebuild
electron-rebuild --version 9.3.5 (the current electron version atom was using at the time)
```

Before publishing to npm:
delete binding.gyp, package-lock.json files and the Electron binary folder